# Can a gravitational field be diluted or shielded?

Tags: gravity

An electromagnetic field can be diluted in a volume by using a dielectric. The polarization of the dielectric material results in the field decreasing in magnitude.

Can a gravitational field be similarly "diluted"?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2767/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

To quote the Wikipedia article on [gravitational shielding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_shielding), "gravitational shielding is considered to be a violation of the equivalence principle and therefore inconsistent with both Newtonian theory and general relativity."  You can also think of this as being due to the fact that mass only comes in one flavor, positive.