# Are there any experiments going related to gravitational shielding?

Tags: gravity, experimental-physics

Is it possible somehow to achieve gravitational shielding? Are there any experiments presently going on or future projects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it theoretically possible to shield gravitational fields or waves?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2767/)

Comment: You may be interested in the history of the [Gravity Research Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Research_Foundation).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, some experiments have been done in the past with negative results, or results that could not be duplicated. The consensus in the scientific community is gravitational shielding does not exist except in science fiction. It is considered to violate the equivalence principle making it inconsistent with both Newtonian theory and the theory of general relativity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does violation of the equivalence principle make it inconsistent with Newtonian theory?